# Htaccess redirect url to share the same css across subdirectories

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How can I make that all the websites in same root directory to share the same CSS files but to make it look like that the CSS is in its subdirectory.

Here its a illustrative example:
This is my directory

```
- assets/
-- css/
--- bootstrap/
---- bootstrap.min.css
- website1.com/
- website2.com/
- website3.com/
```

All the website1, 2 and 3 have their own domain name and none of them has the assets directory.
When I link the css

```
<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

It is actually linking from the root folder.

I hope I explained it good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use something similar like this:

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap/bootstrap-min.css" type="text/css"/>
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)css/(.*)$ http://domain-where-css-is-stored/assets/css/$2
```